# Azure Cosmos DB -- Update Conflict Resolution Policy After Creating the Container

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

The scenario is to update the conflict resolution policy from Last-Writer-Wins to custom conflict resolution.

The example provided in the documentation is to use [CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-manage-conflicts) with specific conflict policy, but it can only be done when creating the container. Is there any other way that I can update after creation?

I know in the Azure portal, there is "Scale & settings" where users can update the conflict resolution, but it gives me below errors when I tried to update.

```
{"code":400,"body":{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Updating conflict resolution policy is currently not supported\"]}
```

Does anyone know why this error shows up? Or maybe there is something in the client SDK side that can be used to update conflict policy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the message suggests this is currently not available for customers Since this is the first time you have encountered this you have 2 options:

1) If your app is new and you can do the rework, You can delete and recreate the collection with new policy from scratch.

2) If it is an old app and you cannot delete and recreate it, Product Team can still do it from backend but you will need to contact the Support for the same.

Do take in account that updating policy when creating new collection is safe, but during run time, if conflict resolution changed, there will be a change of behavior that has to be handled by the application. Able to update the Conflict resolution policy will not be a feature for the safety of the customers. This is done from back end based on request.

Hope this helps.

Thanks
Navtej S

Comment: Cosmos DB product team will not change conflict resolution policies via Support. It is unsafe and not currently supported by the product.